# 'fish_config browse' opens balena etcher instead of the default web browser

Tags: fish

When I type `fish_config browse` in fish to configure it, it opens Balena etcher and not the web browser.

I am on Pop!_OS 22.04 lts and migrated from bash.

Answer (score 0):

`fish_config browse` is a python script that ends up using the python [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module to open a `file://` url.

If that opens Balena Etcher, then that is because on your system that's configured to open `file://` links to .html files. Balena Etcher is an electron app, which means it *is* technically a web browser, so in a poorly configured environment it's easily possible that shows up for .html files.

You will need to reconfigure your environment or set the $BROWSER variable to a different browser.